# smbd (samba daemon) does not listen on ports 139/445

Tags: networking, server, samba, cifs

I am running a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 and having troubles with smbd. `service smbd status` tells me that smbd should be running:

```
   ● smbd.service - LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/smbd; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Die 2016-10-18 17:35:23 CEST; 2s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 24218 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/smbd stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 21980 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/smbd reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 25190 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/smbd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Okt 18 17:35:22 speedy systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)...
Okt 18 17:35:23 speedy smbd[25190]:  * Starting SMB/CIFS daemon smbd
Okt 18 17:35:23 speedy smbd[25190]:    ...done.
Okt 18 17:35:23 speedy systemd[1]: Started LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd).
```

and this can be verified by `ps axf | grep smbd`:

```
25356 pts/2    S+     0:00  |   \_ grep --color=auto smbd
19915 ?        Ss     0:08      \_ /usr/sbin/smbd -D
19919 ?        S      0:00          \_ /usr/sbin/smbd -D
```

However, `netstat -tpln | grep "smbd"` returns nothing and also nmap shows "closed" on ports 139 and 445.

What I tried so far is activating these options in /etc/samba/smb.conf, but it doesn't help:

```
interfaces = enp2s0
bind interfaces only = true
```

I am clueless what else I could try... Any ideas?

Best regards,

Michael

Comment: Re-posted question slightly modified on serverfault: http://serverfault.com/questions/810544/samba-daemon-does-not-work-as-systemd-service-but-works-in-foreground

Comment: In the above output of "systemctl status" it says "active (exited)", which actually means that the daemon is not running. It has to say "active (running)" instead. The output generated by "ps axf" shows smbd running in a container, not on the host. The output of "ps -eo pid,ppid,fname | grep smbd" helps a little more: if there is no "smbd" with a parent ID of "1", smbd most possibly is not running on the host and the other processes are running in containers.

Answer (score 0):

### What causes this problem?

On the same machine, smbd is running in LXC containers. The script that starts the Samba daemon - /etc/init.d/smbd - thinks that the daemon is already running and denies to start another instance, because it is not aware that the smbd process found runs in a container. That's also the reason why Samba started at boot time: at this time the containers haven't been started yet and there was no "other" smbd process. The same applies to other technologies, like Docker.

### How to solve the problem?

Like suggested in [1], the solution is to modify /etc/init.d/smbd:

```
if ! start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --exec /usr/sbin/smbd -- -D; then
```

change to:

```
if ! start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --pidfile /var/run/samba/smbd.pid --exec /usr/sbin/smbd -- -D; then
```

On Ubuntu 16.04.3, this code can be found in line 40. When editing using nano, press Ctrl+W, type "start-stop", and press enter; this will bring you to the correct line.

[1] https://serverfault.com/a/862514/193537